# Stable Legs for Desk

Tags: desk

I currently came into possession of a [desktop from Ikea](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S49110931/) that is sort of like the one in the link but it is 63 inches wide, roughly an inch thick. I am looking to put some legs on it that are about 27-30 inches long. I have came across something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DSZVTI) but I am not sure if the desk would be stable enough. Would those legs in the link be okay or would I be looking for something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Answer (score 1):

The legs you have may or may not provide the stability that you seek.  Hard to say.  The legs you link to probably would work fine for most purposes.  However, a skirt between the legs would improve the stability a good deal.  You can look at getting your own table skirt and legs using the calculator/chooser at Osborne Wood products here:  https://www.osbornewood.com/Skirt.aspx

We created a large counter height combination table and island using two Ikea wood countertops (round edges ripped off lengthwise, and halves mated together with pocket screws), two Ikea base cabinets and the 2 legs and matching skirts from Osborne.  It turned out really good and has ample stability.